# ios - loading decoupled view from nib file

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nib

I am having difficulty with something that seems to be trivial. I am following this project https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Blog.UIView_from_Xib and trying to implement the **decoupled** way of loading a view from a nib file. I was not able to get the desired result in my app (nothing shows up and I get no crashes either) so I did the following:

1. I took the project from Github https://github.com/eppz/iOS.Blog.UIView_from_Xib
2. I then proceeded to duplicate the files in the "decoupled" group and name it something trivial like "decoupled2". Basically I am creating a whole new class that stands on its own with its own nib file.
3. I then changed all of the internal tags and class references. Then I made sure that all of the new references were pointing to this new class.
4. At this point I added a 6th button to the main VC and made sure to call the right method for my new "decoupled2" class when this 6th button is pressed.

**PROBLEM:** Everything runs but the view from nib does not show up. Debugging view hierarchy shows nothing. Clicking the 5th button still works, so I didn't break the existing code. Why won't the newly created nib file show up?

This seems rather simple, just duplicate what already works in a project that already works and it will work...or not. What am I missing? Thank you for your help.

I have spent a few days on the problem already. Lots of research but nothing of use so far.

Comment: Maybe it could help if you post the code how the button is created and then the code that executes the click.

Answer (score 0):

I re-did the task and it worked this time. 
Maybe restarting Xcode 8.0 was the key or something else that is under the hood.